# Handling circular import with blueprints & async tasks using rq

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use `rq` & `redis` for handling asynchronous tasks. Requirement is that the task will do some operations in background and will update the database directly.

So far, I am able to do the required setup and tasks work perfectly as long as no database interaction is done. When I incorporated the code to trigger database query, I got an error that the application context is needed. Now, when I try to use that, I started getting error for circular import. I am already using blueprints but could not figure out the way to fix it.

I started with this [boilerplate](https://github.com/sarbjit87/flask_boilerplate) and then modified/added new files as below :-

**app/utils/worker.py**

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'low', 'default']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

**app/utils/tasks.py**

```
import sys
import time
from flask import Blueprint

from app.auth.models import User
from app.config import Config
from app import db, create_app

task_bp = Blueprint('task_bp', __name__)

flask_app = create_app(Config)
flask_app.app_context().push()

def background_task():
    print("Task Started")
    user = User.query.get(1)
    print(user)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Task Completed")
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app.config import Config

from app.utils.worker import conn
from rq import Queue
import rq_dashboard

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth_bp.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()

q = Queue(connection=conn)

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(flask_app)
    migrate.init_app(flask_app,db)
    bcrypt.init_app(flask_app)
    login_manager.init_app(flask_app)
    mail.init_app(flask_app)

    from app.auth.routes import auth_bp
    from app.main.routes import main_bp
    from app.errors.handlers import errors_bp
    from app.utils.tasks import task_bp
    flask_app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(main_bp)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(task_bp)

    flask_app.config.from_object(rq_dashboard.default_settings)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(rq_dashboard.blueprint, url_prefix="/rq")

    return flask_app
```

**app/main/routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, request, Blueprint
from app import db, q

from app.utils.tasks import background_task

main_bp = Blueprint('main_bp', __name__)

@main_bp.route("/")
@main_bp.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home')

@main_bp.route("/about")
def about():
    q.enqueue(background_task)
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')
```

**Error :-**

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./app/utils/tasks.py", line 11, in <module>
    flask_app = create_app(Config)
  File "./app/__init__.py", line 34, in create_app
    from app.main.routes import main_bp
  File "./app/main/routes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.utils.tasks import background_task
ImportError: cannot import name 'background_task' from 'app.utils.tasks' (./app/utils/tasks.py)
```

Appreciate if someone can help me resolve it and suggest some best practices using `rq` and blueprints.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by moving the import statements inside the task function body. I am not sure if this is the right way to resolve it or if there is other clean solution for the same.

```
import sys
import time
from app.auth.models import User

def background_task():
    from app.config import Config
    from app import db, create_app
    flask_app = create_app(Config)
    flask_app.app_context().push()
    print("Task Started")
    user = User.query.get(1)
    print(user)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Task Completed")
```